# i need to match 2 string and adding line break after match string

Tags: php, string, match

i need to match 2 string and adding line break after match string for example

```
$string1="<p>he adventures of adolescence had taught Piet Barol that he</p>";
$matching_with_string="he adventures
of adolescence had
taught Piet Barol 
that he";
```

i need string 1 output will be same as string

> $matching_with_string

can someone help me out!

Comment: What is your match string in above code

Comment: Question is unclear from this summary, You need to tell us what you really want to do (what is inputs)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your requirement:

```
if(strstr($string1,$matching_with_string)){
//your code
}
```